# Emulating tablet e.g. Galaxy in latest version of Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

How can I emulate the Galaxy tab (or any Android tablet really) in the latest Android SDK's emulator?  I tried starting the SDK Manager, switching the "Sort By" selection to the "Repository" radio button, selecting the "Galaxy Tab by Samsung Electronics" check box, clicking the "Install 1 package" button ... after which it shows "SDK Platform Android 2.2, API8, revision 3..." as a dependency but when I select that and press "Install" it fails with the log showing:

Preparing to install archives
Downloading SDK Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\android-2.2_r03-linux.zip (Access is denied)

What is going on here, I wish whoever's in charge of the documentation would get it together, all the "official" references still talk about the "SDK and AVD Manager" program that doesn't even exist in this latest version of the SDK.

Comment: Check here..http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: For what exactly?  I already have the SDK installed and running, just not for a tablet device.

Comment: sorry...i thought u looking for a documentation on installing SDK..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acting on a hunch, I found the somewhat embarrassing solution ... it was due to the SDK by default being installed in a protected folder of Windows 7 (Program Files x86).  Once I moved the whole android-sdk folder to the desktop, it worked fine.